# Automatic redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?  I'm trying to redirect people to the login page if they've been inactive for a length of time.

```
<script>
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
     time = new Date().getTime();
 });

 function refresh() {
     if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 4200000) 
        window.location.href = '/login.cfm'

     else 

         setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
 }

 setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
</script>
```

seems to work now!

Comment: Can u plz tel me whr login.cfm page is located? If it is present in any folder then give absolute path. For more details see link http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Comment: It's in the FOH which is where IIS is pointed - so presumably just /login.cfm will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
window.location.href
```